# How to remove a picture from library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to remove a picture after saving it on the phone, I save it this way:

```
var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
```

But is it possible to remove it too? I see just a Delete for songs:

```
mediaLibrary.Delete(song);
```

it is a WP8 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
Please see: [Delete image from MediaLibrary.SavePictures](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/e0f97471-9ca6-4129-bffc-ff36272a80cf/delete-image-from-medialibrarysavepictures)

> There is no way to delete any content from the user's library. Once you've saved a picture,   the user will always have that picture unless they personally go delete it.